# jersey spring autowiring nullPointerException

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jersey, restful-url

I have a session-scoped bean (Ama04Service) in Spring that is set within the web context. I have a task that runs as a Callable, and I need access to this bean from jersey web services. How should I accomplish this? If I simply attempt autowiring the bean the first call of Ama04ServiceImpl (public Response verifNum) the autowiring run successfully, then if i call an another method (clickReponse) in the jersey web service(Ama_04Service) I get NullPointerException
this looks like sprine re-instantiate the autowired bean 
please any idea ? 
thanks in advance.

The session-scoped bean I am injecting looks like this:

```
Service("ama04Service")
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class Ama04ServiceImpl implements Ama04Service, LineListener {   

////some code here//////
}
```

the jersey web service that calls session-scoped bean looks like this

```
@Path("/ama04")
public class Ama_04Service {

@Autowired
Ama04Service ama04Service;
@Autowired
Ama01Service ama01Service;
@Autowired
Ama03Service ama03Service;
@Autowired
ResourceBundleService resourceBundleService;

@GET
@Path("/quest/{date}/{numDonn}/{language}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response verifNum(@PathParam("numDonn") final String numDonn,
        @PathParam("date") final String date,
        @PathParam("language") final String language) {

///////// some code here///////

@GET
@Path("/clickRepons/{numDonn}/{occRep}/{occ}/{date}/{language}")
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public String clickReponse(@PathParam("numDonn") final String numDonn,
        @PathParam("occRep") int occRep, @PathParam("occ") int occ,
        @PathParam("date") final String date,
        @PathParam("language") final String language) {
    Ama4 currentAma = new Ama4();
}
```

Comment: I met the very same problem as yours and have not figure it out yet. Did you succeed it?